# Yii FileLogging not working on 1 server and working on the other

Tags: php, yii, error-logging

A client has two diffent servers with the same application build with the Yii framework. The logging configuration of both environments is exact the same:

```
'log' => array(
               'class' => 'CLogRouter',
               'routes' => array(
                   array(
                       'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                       'levels' => 'error, warning, info',
                   )                        
               ),
        ),
```

The access rights to the folder "runtime" are set to 755 on DEV and 777 on LIVE. 
It is working on DEV but on LIVE there are no files created. The runtime folder is empty.

If the logs files are deleted, does it stop working? Does Yii need empty .log and .log.# files to begin with?

What else can be the problem?

Comment: Is debug level set in index.php file?
// remove the following lines when in production mode

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message

defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);

Comment: But when I set YII_DEBUG to true it shows complete stacktraces when an error occures to the user. I don't want that on the production site/api.

Comment: Do your .log file exists? if not then creat it manually and then try. Hopefully it will work.